# Left AirPods in Washing Machine

Tags: damage, airpods

I stupidly left my AirPods in the washing machine through a whole cycle. I took them out, hand dried them, and they were surprisingly still working. I used them for about an hour after that and then all of a sudden they shut off.

Now, they won't turn on at all. I've tried holding down the button for 15 seconds and re-charging them with no luck.

Any ideas for how to fix this problem? Are they permanently dead?

Comment: @BasilBourque comments are to clarify the post. If you want to answer "bag of rice" please put that in as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Apple support can quote you a repair. Since they have batteries and several processors inside each, immersion and agitation for tens of minutes likely caused an overload / short circuit which will be followed by rapid corrosion of metal in the device.

Answer (score 0):

## Bag of rice

Perhaps the [bag of dried rice trick](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rice%20iphone&t=ffip&ia=web) as commonly done for iPhones.

Ideally you would have done something like that *before* turning them on. May be too late if you fried the circuitry.